# If $G$ is a finite group and $(ab)^3= a^3b^3$,

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Group with an endomorphism that is “almost” abelian is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/group-with-an-endomorphism-that-is-almost-abelian-is-abelian)

If $G$ is a finite group and $(ab)^3= a^3b^3$, and $3 \nmid o(G)$, then how do I prove that $G$ is abelian?