# Let $G$ be a group such that for all $x,y \in G, (xy)^3 = x^3y^3$ and there's no element with order $3$. Show that $xy^2=y^2x$ and $G$ is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a group such that for all $x,y \in G, (xy)^3 = x^3y^3$ and there's no element with order $3$. Show that $xy^2=y^2x$ and $G$ is abelian.

Any idea or some hints?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: I think you need to assume that $G$ is finite.

Comment: from $(xy)^3 = x^3y^3$, i get $(yx)^2 = x^2y^2$. and then how?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057) is a duplicate for the case when $G$ is finite. I am guessing that it is false in general, but I don't know an infinite counterexample.

Comment: I gave a solution to this problem in sci.math 19 years ago. [Here's a link](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sci.math/2lQawx5kddg/discussion)

Answer (score 3):

$G$ is finite from the tags, though it is not stated.

From $(ab)^3 = a^3b^3$, we get that $(ab)^2 = (ab)^3(ab)^{-1} = a^3b^3b^{-1}a^{-1} = a^3b^2a^{-1}$. Thus, $abab = a^3b^2a^{-1}$ or $(ba)^2 = a^2b^2$.

So $b^3a^3= (ba)^3 = (ba)(ba)^2 = ba^3b^2$. Therefore, $b^2a^3 = a^3b^2$, so every cube commutes with every square.

Let $g\in G$. Since $|g|$ is not divisible by $3$, $|g^3| = |g|/\gcd(|g|,3) = |g|$, so $\langle g^3\rangle = \langle g\rangle$. Therefore, there exists $k\gt 0$ such that $g=(g^3)^k = (g^k)^3$. In particular, every element of $G$ is a cube.

This means that *every* element of $G$ commutes with ever square, so $G^2\subseteq Z(G)$.

But now we have that $a^3b^3 = aa^2b^2b = ab^2a^2b$, so $a^2b^2=b^2a^2 = (ab)^2$. And it is well known that from $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ we may conclude that $G$ is abelian.

---

As stated in the [sci.math thread I linked to in the comments](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/sci.math/2lQawx5kddg/discussion), a variant that does not require the assumption of finiteness is:

> Let $G$ be a group with no $3$-torsion in which $(ab)^3 = a^3b^3$ for all $a,b\in G$. Then $G$ is abelian.

This is the problem as stated, if we don’t look at the tags to find out we are supposed to assume $G$ is finite. This statement is also correct.

*Proof:* as above, we know that every cube commutes with every square. Hence:
$$\begin{align*}
[a,b]^3 &= (a^{-1}b^{-1}ab)^3\\
&= a^{-3}b^{-3}a^3b^3\\
&= a^{-3}b^{-3}b^2a^3b\\
&= a^{-3}b^{-1}a^3b\\
&= [a^3,b].
\end{align*}$$
In particular, $[a,b^2]^3= [a^3,b^2] = 1$ (because squares and cubes commute). Since $G$ has no $3$-torsion by assumption, this means that $[a,b^2]=1$, so squares are central in $G$.

Now we can proceed as before: $(ab)^3 = a^3b^3 = ab^2a^2b$, so $(ba)^2 = b^2a^2$ and we conclude that $G$ as abelian as before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint to get you started:

$(xy)^3 = x^3y^3 \iff y(xy)x = yxyx = xxyy = x(xy)y$

You need to prove that $xyy=yyx$ and then use that to prove $xy=yx$.

Comment: from $(xy)^3 = x^3y^3$, i have $(yx)^2 = x^2y^2$.

Comment: is $y(xy)x = x(xy)y$ enough to prove?

Comment: @gt6989b can you show that how to prove $xyy=yyx$ ?

Comment: @Subhajit https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057

Comment: $x^2y^2 = (xy)^2 = xyxy \Leftrightarrow xyy = yxy \Leftrightarrow xy=yx$. But, how to prove $xy^2 = y^2x$ ?

Comment: Oh, I see. Multiply on the both side of $yxyx = xxyy$ on the left side by $x$, to get $xyxyx = xxxyy \dots (1)$. Since $(xy)^2 = x^2y^2$, then from $(1)$, we get $xxyyx = xxxyy$. By the cancelation $xx$ on the left side, we get $yyx = xyy$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y \in G$. First, we'll prove that $xy^2 = y^2x$. From $(xy)^3 = x^3y^3$,
\begin{align*}
xyxyxy &= xxxyyy \\
yxyx &= xxyy \\
\end{align*}
we obtain $(yx)^2 = x^2y^2 \dots (1)$.
Next, consider that
\begin{align*}
(xy)^9 &= x^9y^9 \\
(yx)^8 &= x^8y^8 \\
(x^2y^2)^4 &= x^8y^8 \ (from \ (1)) \\
xxyyxxyyxxyyxxyy &= xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyy \\
(y^2x^2)^3 &= (x^2)^3(y^2)^3 \\
(y^2)^3(x^2)^3 &= (x^2)^3(y^2)^3
\end{align*}
Since there are no elements in $G$ with order $3$, we get $y^2x^2 = x^2y^2$.
Now, consider $(1)$.

\begin{align*}
yxyx &= xxyy \\
xyxyx &= xxxyy \\
xxyyx &= xxxyy \\
yyx &= xyy ...  (2)
\end{align*}

Hence, $xy^2 = y^2x$. Next, from $(2)$, we get

\begin{align*}
xyy &= yyx \\
xxyy &= xyyx \\
yxyx &= xyyx \\
yxy &= xyy \\
yx &= xy
\end{align*}

Hence, $xy=yx$, for all $x,y \in G$, which proves that $G$ is abelian.

Is it correct?

Comment: To prove that there's exist $z \in G$ such that $z=g^3$ for all $g \in G$, we just show that there is automorphism from $G$ to $G$ defined by $g \rightarrow g^3$. Is this true?

Comment: No, you don’t; you just need to show that the map is bijective (you don’t need to show it is a homomorphism). You tagged this as “finite groups”: the order of any $g$ is not divisible by $3$, so the order of $g^3$ is the same as the order of $g$. That means that $\langle g\rangle = \langle g^3\rangle$, and that tell syou that $g=(g^3)^k = (g^k)^3$ for some $k$.

Comment: So, if I can prove that the map is bijective, then, what next?

Comment: Let $g \in G$. Then, $g^{\frac{1}{3}} \in G$. Thus, $f(g^{\frac{1}{3}}) = (g^{\frac{1}{3}})^3 = g$. Hence, $f$ is surjective. Is it true?

Comment: “$g^{1/3}$” is nonsense until you prove that there is a unique element whose cube is $g$. So what you wrote is a circular argument. The map is surjective for the reason I gave you: there is a power of $g$ whose cube is $g$. Once you know it is surjective, it is a map from a finite set to a finite set, hence bijective.

Comment: Oh, I see. From your statement above, there is $k$ such that $(g^k)^3 = g$, then the map is surjective, right?

Comment: If there are no elements with order $3$, how we concluded that the order of $g^3$ is same with $g$, for $g \in G$ ?

Comment: The order of $g^k$ is $|g|/\gcd(|g|,k)$. This is a basic property of cyclic groups.